# google Cloud Speech-to-Text dtmf support?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

We need a possibility also to identify DTMFs.
Scenario:
On a phone conversation we ask the user "Please enter id number".
We stream the audio to google cloud speech to text.
We would like to support both options at the same time: (a) user says the id nubmer (b) user presses the id numbers using phone keys (DTMf).

Answer (score 0):

DTMF seems can't be detected using Cloud Speech-to-Text. I've opened a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117762395) on your behalf requesting this feature. You can star the issue and follow the progress.

As a workaround you can use [scipy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/signal.html) library's [spectogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html#scipy.signal.spectrogram) method to detect the unique [DTMF frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling#Keypad).

Comment: Thanks Yurci for opening a public issue feature request. I've added comments there.